# Get random point within a multipolygon

Tags: openlayers-2

Can somebody help me in getting a random point which lies inside multipolygon,i.e I have a multipolygon, then i want to get a random point which lies inside that multipolygon

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. I don't know of a single function that does this, but you could perhaps make something using logic like "find bounding box for multipolygon, pick random value between upper and lower bounds of bounding box in each of X and Y direction, check if resulting point intersects the multipolygon (http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.6/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Collection-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Collection.intersects) and iterate until intersection".

Comment: nice idea.... it works

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to PostGIS, see [UserWikiRandomPoint](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UserWikiRandomPoint)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Geospatial Modeling Environment](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/) tools (genrandompnts) to generate random data points inside a polygon. This is free tool, and runs with almost all ArcGIS versions.